# How to iterate (keys, values) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, iterator

I have a dictionary that has the format of

```
dictionary = {0: {object}, 1:{object}, 2:{object}}
```

How can I iterate through this dictionary by doing something like

```
for ((key, value) in dictionary) {
    //Do stuff where key would be 0 and value would be the object
}
```

Comment: `for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))`, need Babel.

Comment: @elclanrs Its in ES2016 and it is not standardized yet :-)

Comment: @dooagain, it is not an array in this question.

Answer (score 994, accepted):

## tl;dr

1. In ECMAScript 2017, just call `Object.entries(yourObj)`.
2. In ECMAScript 2015, it is possible with `Map`s.
3. In ECMAScript 5, it is not possible.

## ECMAScript 2017

ECMAScript 2017 introduced a new [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function. You can use this to iterate the object as you wanted.

```
'use strict';

const object = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

### Output

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

---

## ECMAScript 2015

In ECMAScript 2015, there is not `Object.entries` but you can use `Map` objects instead and iterate over them with [`Map.prototype.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries). Quoting the example from that page,

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("0", "foo");
myMap.set(1, "bar");
myMap.set({}, "baz");

var mapIter = myMap.entries();

console.log(mapIter.next().value); // ["0", "foo"]
console.log(mapIter.next().value); // [1, "bar"]
console.log(mapIter.next().value); // [Object, "baz"]
```

Or iterate with [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), like this

```
'use strict';

var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("0", "foo");
myMap.set(1, "bar");
myMap.set({}, "baz");

for (const entry of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(entry);
}
```

### Output

```
[ '0', 'foo' ]
[ 1, 'bar' ]
[ {}, 'baz' ]
```

Or

```
for (const [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

### Output

```
0 foo
1 bar
{} baz
```

---

## ECMAScript 5:

No, it's not possible with objects.

You should either iterate with [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), or [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), like this

```
for (var key in dictionary) {
    // check if the property/key is defined in the object itself, not in parent
    if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {           
        console.log(key, dictionary[key]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `if` condition above is necessary only if you want to iterate over the properties which are the `dictionary` object's very own. Because `for..in` will iterate through all the inherited enumerable properties.

Or

```
Object.keys(dictionary).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, dictionary[key]);
});
```

Comment: A basic doubt here. I landed here looking for how to do this in node.js, which is javascript on server side. How do I know which ES version applies in my case. Also, in case of regular javascript users, what is the proper way to support as I understand that ES version depends on the client's browser?

Comment: @SandeepanNath You can use websites like https://node.green/ to know if a particular ES feature is supported in your Node.js. As far as browsers are concerned, people generally target the version which is widely supported, in this case, ES5. Apart from this, transpilers (like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) help convert ES2015+ code to ES5.

Comment: I like `Object.keys(dictionary).forEach(function(key) {…` very readable, and compatible.

Comment: `Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, val]) => {...});`

Comment: ECMAScript 2015 solution  above threw ["TypeScript and Iterator: Type 'IterableIterator<T>' is not an array type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218765/typescript-and-iterator-type-iterableiteratort-is-not-an-array-type) but plain ol [myMap().foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) worked well.

Comment: To avoid excessive indentation, it would be neater to write for (var key in dictionary) {if (!parameters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {continue;} console.log(key, dictionary[key]);}

Answer (score 157):

Try this:

```
dict = {0:{1:'a'}, 1:{2:'b'}, 2:{3:'c'}}
for (var key in dict){
  console.log( key, dict[key] );
}

0 Object { 1="a"}
1 Object { 2="b"}
2 Object { 3="c"}
```

Answer (score 96):

**WELCOME TO 2020 *Drools in ES6***

Theres some pretty old answers in here - take advantage of destructuring. In my opinion this is without a doubt the nicest (very readable) way to iterate an object.

```js
const myObject = {
    nick: 'cage',
    phil: 'murray',
};

Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    console.log("The key: ", k)
    console.log("The value: ", v)
})
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned by Lazerbeak, `map` allows you to cycle an object and use the key and value to make an array.

```js
const myObject = {
    nick: 'cage',
    phil: 'murray',
};

const myArray = Object.entries(myObject).map(([k, v]) => {
    return `The key '${k}' has a value of '${v}'`;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

**Edit 2:**

To explain what is happening in the line of code:

```
Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([k,v]) => {}
```

`Object.entries()` converts our object to an array of arrays:

```
[["nick", "cage"], ["phil", "murray"]]
```

Then we use forEach on the outer array:

```
1st loop: ["nick", "cage"]
2nd loop: ["phil", "murray"]
```

Then we "destructure" the value (which we know will always be an array) with `([k,v])` so `k` becomes the first name and `v` becomes the last name.

Comment: Just a note: if you replace `forEach` with `map` above, it's then possible to aggregate values. `map` will then return a list of said values, thus potentially simplifying the code in other ways.

Answer (score 76):

The `Object.entries()` method has been specified in ES2017 (and is [supported in all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-entries)):

```
for (const [ key, value ] of Object.entries(dictionary)) {
    // do something with `key` and `value`
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `Object.entries()` takes an object like `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }` and turns it into an array of key-value pairs: `[ [ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ], [ 'c', 3 ] ]`.
- With `for ... of` we can loop over the entries of the so created array.
- Since we are *guaranteed* that each of the so iterated array items is itself a two-entry array, we can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to directly assign variables `key` and `value` to its first and second item.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
var value;
for (var key in dictionary) {
    value = dictionary[key];
    // your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can do something like this :

```
dictionary = {'ab': {object}, 'cd':{object}, 'ef':{object}}
var keys = Object.keys(dictionary);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length;i++){
   //keys[i] for key
   //dictionary[keys[i]] for the value
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! I love how your answer works in ECMAscript 5 despite the accepted and most upvoted answer saying it's not possible. You deserve all a lot more upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

I think the fast and easy way is

```
Object.entries(event).forEach(k => {
    console.log("properties ... ", k[0], k[1]); });
```

just check the documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: even better: Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); 
});

Answer (score 2):

using swagger-ui.js

you can do this -

```
_.forEach({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, function(n, key) {
    console.log(n, key);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

As an improvement to the accepted answer, in order to reduce nesting, you could do this instead, provided that the key is not inherited:

```
for (var key in dictionary) {
    if (!dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }
    console.log(key, dictionary[key]);
}
```

Edit: info about `Object.hasOwnProperty` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below script.

```
var obj={1:"a",2:"b",c:"3"};
for (var x=Object.keys(obj),i=0;i<x.length,key=x[i],value=obj[key];i++){
    console.log(key,value);
}
```

outputs
1 a
2 b
c 3

Comment: #will output #c 3
    #1 a
    #2 b

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your answer, code alone is less helpful. Also, you can edit your answer, comments are not meant to be an extension to the answer in the way you are using them

Answer (score -3):

You can use JavaScript `forEach` Loop:

```
myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    console.log('value: ', value);
    console.log('key: ', key);
});
```

Comment: No, they can't. `myMap` is a plain object, not an array.

Comment: it works for me though https://plnkr.co/edit/9KaRqXWZ38NyVTs3?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: You've used a `Map` object instead of the plain object that was used in the question.

Comment: Oh I see, I came across this question while googling for the `Map` object. My bad.

Comment: @SeverinToldo but it works for map supported by es5