# How to loop through a JSON object with typescript (Angular2)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular2 and I am trying to loop through a JSON object that I am getting back from a GET request but can't work it out.

**My JSON object:**

```
{
    Results: [{
        Time: "2017-02-11T08:15:01.000+00:00",
        Id: "data-mopdsjkajskda",
        AuthorId: "58fSDNJD"
    }, {
        Time: "2017-03-11T06:23:34.000+00:00",
        Id: "data-2371212hjb1",
        AuthorId: "43555HHHJ"
    }, {
        Time: "2017-04-11T07:05:11.000+00:00",
        Id: "data-kjskdha22112",
        AuthorId: "XDSJKJSDH"
    }]
}
```

**Part of my Angular script:**

```
interface res {
    Time: string;
    Id: string;
    AuthorId: string;
}
export class AppComponent {
    results: res;
    constructor(private _httpservice: HTTPService) {}
    this._httpservice.getQuery().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.results = data.Results
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('Done')
    );
}
```

I do get the data back - which is great. However, I want to push the Ids into an array. In Javascript I would do this:

```
var ids = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
    ids.push(data.Results[i].Id)
}
```

The array after the push:

```
ids = ['data-mopdsjkajskda', 'data-2371212hjb1', 'data-kjskdha22112'];
```

I am struggling to find a way to achieve the same results with Angular2. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should be Javasript question. Angular has nothing to do with for loop. Anyway, you can use this instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34913733/11457981) answer helped me well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming your json object from your GET request looks like the one you posted above simply do:

```
let list: string[] = [];

json.Results.forEach(element => {
    list.push(element.Id);
});
```

Or am I missing something that prevents you from doing it this way?

Comment: Oh perfect, that worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 28):

ECMAScript 6 introduced the [`let`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) statement. You can use it in a `for` statement.

```
var ids:string = [];

for(let result of this.results){
   ids.push(result.Id);
}
```