# Getting access to the JSON data in a object

Tags: javascript, json, function, object

My JSON:

```js
const tests = {
"test 1": {
    "name": "name 1",
    "last name": "prid",
},
"test 2": {
    "name": "name 1",
    "last name": "prid",
},
};
```

And this is my code:

```js
const obj = {
    enterSom: function(name) {
        console.log(name)
    },

    enterName: function(tests) {
        for (test in tests) {
            let name = test["name"]

            this.enterSom(name)
        }
    },
};
```

The results:

```js
undefined
undefined
```

When I create something like this:

```js
// first case
console.log(tests["test 1"]["name"])
// result -> name 1

// second case
for (test in tests) {
    console.log(test)
}
// result -> test 1
// result -> test 2
```

And when I extract the loop from my code:

```js
for (test in tests) {
    console.log(test["name"])
}
// result -> undefined
// result -> undefined
```

How can I get the JSON data when the data are nested like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate (keys, values) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913675/how-to-iterate-keys-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. Only `for (key in obj)` and not `for (value in obj)`

```js
const tests = {
  "test 1": {
    "name": "name 1",
    "last name": "prid",
  },
  "test 2": {
    "name": "name 2",
    "last name": "prid",
  },
};


const obj = {
  enterSom: function(name) {
    console.log(name)
  },

  enterName: function(tests) {
    for (test in tests) {
      let name = tests[test]["name"]

      this.enterSom(name)
    }
  },
};

obj.enterName(tests);
```