# My fetch request to openlibrary is getting caught

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to write a fetch request to the openlibrary API but so far it keeps getting caught and returning a console.log error. I'm thinking I'm entering the URL incorrectly but I'm not sure. I've tried rephrasing it a couple of ways but so far hasn't worked. I'm relatively new to writing fetch.

It's making a search of ISBN.
It's . I also wanted to verify I have the data property for ebook availability in the correct format when I refer to it to create the text.

```
var fetchRequest = function() {

          var isbn = '0553283685';
          //var searchURL = `https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + ISBN${isbn}&format=json&jscmd=data`; 

          var searchURL = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + isbn + "&format=json&jscmd=data";
          
          fetch(searchURL)
          .then(function(response) {
              return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(response2) {
              return response2.items.map(function(book) {
                createBookList(book)
              })   

            })  
          .catch( function()  {
              console.log(`There was an error with the fetch request`);       
          }); 
      }
```

My createBookList function:

```
   var createBookList = function(book) {   

      var li = document.createElement('li');        
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      var singleBookRow = document.createElement('div');        
  
      var bookEPUB = document.createElement('p');
      var bookPDF = document.createElement('p');
      var bookTEXT = document.createElement('p');
      var bookREAD = document.createElement('p');

              bookEPUB.textContent = book.ebooks.availability.epub_url;
              bookPDF.textContent = book.ebooks.availability.pdf_url;
              bookTEXT.textContent = book.ebooks.availability.text_url;
              bookREAD.textContent = book.ebooks.availability.read_url;


        div.appendChild(bookEPUB);
        div.appendChild(bookPDF);
        div.appendChild(bookTEXT);
        singleBookRow.appendChild(bookREAD);
        singleBookRow.appendChild(div);
        li.appendChild(singleBookRow);
        booksList.appendChild(li);
  
        li.classList.add('list-group-item');
        singleBookRow.classList.add('row');
        div.classList.add('columns-large-4');

     
        /// 'Check availability' button 

        var checkAvailability = document.createElement('input');   
        checkAvailability.type='button';   
        checkAvailability.onclick=(book);    
        div.append(checkAvailability);     
        
    }
```

Comment: show your createBookList function. The URL is working fine.

Comment: "an error" ... why not do `.catch(function(error) { console.error(error); }` then you can start actual debugging for yourself, since you won't get "an error", you'll get THE error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, print the error:

```js
// omit stuff...
          .catch( function(e)  {
              console.log(e)
              console.log(`There was an error with the fetch request`);       
          }); 
// omit stuff...
```

from error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`, we can know that the response type is unexpected. let's check it:

```js
// omit stuff...
          .then(function(response2) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response2))
              return response2.items.map(function(book) {
// omit stuff...
```

what's this? a dictionary.

```js
{"ISBN:0553283685":{"url":"https://openlibrary.org/books/OL16710277M/Hypérion","key":"/books/OL16710277M","title":"Hypérion"}, ...}'
```

so, it turns out that you can't parse the result this way. To iterate over dictionary, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913675/how-to-iterate-keys-values-in-javascript):

```js
(function() {

          var isbn = '0553283685';
          //var searchURL = `https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + ISBN${isbn}&format=json&jscmd=data`; 

          var searchURL = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + isbn + "&format=json&jscmd=data";
          
          fetch(searchURL)
          .then(function(response) {
              return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(response2) {
              books = []
              for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(response2)) {
                  books.append(createBookList(book))
              }
              return books

            })
```