# How to sort a map by value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary

How to sort this map by value?

```
var map = new Map();
map.set('orange', 10);
map.set('apple', 5);
map.set('banana', 20);
map.set('cherry', 13);
```

Comment: `Map` is a data structure, which is not supposed to be able to be sorted. It stores key-value pairs, and there is not much sense in sorting a hashtable. You can convert it to an array, and sort this array, if you want.

Comment: I agree you should not depend on the sort of a Map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a dictionary by value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500316/sort-a-dictionary-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: use plain Objects instead of Maps to store sorted alphabetically-keyed key:value pairs.

Comment: The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yo could take a different approach and change [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) of [`Map.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) for a custom sorted result.

```js
var map = new Map();

map.set("orange", 10);
map.set("apple", 5);
map.set("banana", 20);
map.set("cherry", 13);

map[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield* [...this.entries()].sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
}

for (let [key, value] of map) {     // get data sorted
    console.log(key + ' ' + value);
}

console.log([...map]);              // sorted order
console.log([...map.entries()]);    // original insertation order
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think this is cool but should be used very carefully so you're not sorting already sorted lists.

Comment: In fact I think it would be good to add an "isSorted" property, and if so then don't sort.  

One could go further and add a [Symbol.set] generator for binary insertion, and [Symbol.get] for binary search which forked based on the isSorted flag.  

I'm concerned though about the long term safety of this approach.  I think indirection would likely be more prudent.

Answer (score 168):

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("a",3);
myMap.set("c",4);
myMap.set("b",1);
myMap.set("d",2);

// sort by value
const mapSort1 = new Map([...myMap.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]));
console.log(mapSort1);
// Map(4) {"c" => 4, "a" => 3, "d" => 2, "b" => 1}

const mapSort2 = new Map([...myMap.entries()].sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]));
console.log(mapSort2);
// Map(4) {"b" => 1, "d" => 2, "a" => 3, "c" => 4}

// sort by key
const mapSort3 = new Map([...myMap.entries()].sort());
console.log(mapSort3);
// Map(4) {"a" => 3, "b" => 1, "c" => 4, "d" => 2}

const mapSort4 = new Map([...myMap.entries()].reverse());
console.log(mapSort4);
// Map(4) {"d" => 2, "b" => 1, "c" => 4, "a" => 3}
```

Comment: Thanks! You method is very clean. However could you please explain the `new Map([...myMap.entries()])`. Is this method compatible with Internet Explorer?

Comment: [Looks like you can't use the array spread operator in IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_arrays)

Comment: Yes this is what I thought. Any idea of a clean method that would work with IE?

Answer (score 10):

You can shorten the function and use this in ES6- using arrow function (lambda)

```
 let m2= new Map([...m.entries()].sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]))
```

Answer (score 6):

In ES6 you can do it like this: (assume your Map object is `m`).

```
[...m].map(e =>{ return e[1];}).slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b; 
});
```

the spread operator turns a Map object into an array, then takes out the second element of each subarray to build a new array, then sort it. If you want to sort in descending order just replace `a - b` with `b - a`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use list maps instead of map only.
Try this:

```
var yourListMaps = [];
var a = {quantity: 10, otherAttr: 'tmp1'};
var b = {quantity: 20, otherAttr: 'tmp2'};
var c = {quantity: 30, otherAttr: 'tmp3'};
yourListMaps.push(a);
yourListMaps.push(b);
yourListMaps.push(c);
```

And if you want to sort by quantity, you can:

```
// Sort c > b > a
yourListMaps.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.quantity - a.quantity;
});
```

or

```
// Sort a > b > c
yourListMaps.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.quantity - b.quantity;
});
```

Comment: this didnt work. i get result in insertion order only

Comment: try again now? I think you copy or write something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

To sort a map object use the below code.

```
const map = new Map();
map.set("key","value");
map.set("key","value");

const object = Object.keys(map.sort().reduce((a,b) => (a[k] = map[a], b), {});

console.log(object);

//This will work to sort a map by key.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several valid answers here but I think the "ordered map" aspect complicates and confuses things unnecessarily.

Assuming it is sufficient to get a list of the *keys* in the map sorted by value, rather than a map whose entries are sorted by value, then something like this works:

```
var map = {
  orange: 10,
  apple: 5,
  banana: 20,
  cherry: 13
}

var sorted_keys = Object.keys(map).sort(function(a,b) { return map[a] - map[b]; });
```

which yields:

```
["apple", "orange", "cherry", "banana"]
```

This is a little less elegant if you actually want to iterate over the map entries (now you need to iterate over the array of sorted keys and fetch the values instead) but:

1. This logic is much easier for my simple mind to follow and to remember.
2. There's a pretty common use case for "sort this map by value" in which you actually want the sorted list of keys: using a map to keep a tally. (E.g., iterating over the words in a file using a map to keep try of how often each word appears then sorting that map to get a list of words by frequency.)

For the general case in which the values in the map aren't necessarily numeric, replace the comparator function (the function passed to `Object.keys(map).sort`) with something like:

```
function(a, b) {
  return (a < b) ? -1 : ( (a > b) ? 1 : 0 );
}
```

(which is essentially:

```
function(a, b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

but using the ternary (`? :`) operator.)

But bear in mind that the behavior of JavaScript's `<` and `>` operators is sometimes a little counter-intuitive with mixed types so depending on the values in your map you may want to include explicit type-casting logic in your comparator.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to sort a Map by value but my key is a number and value is a string. (Map<number, string>), and wanted to do it using **TypeScript**.

This is what worked for me, using [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
let json = [
    {
        "key": 2952,
        "value": "Sample Text"
    },
    {
        "key": 2961,
        "value": "Sample Text 1"
    },
    {
        "key": 2962,
        "value": "1Sample Text"
    },
    {
        "key": 2987,
        "value": "3Sample Text"
    },
    {
        "key": 2988,
        "value": "#Sample Text"
    },
    {
        "key": 4585,
        "value": "Ö Sample Text"
    },
    {
        "key": 4594,
        "value": "@Sample Text"
    }
]

let myMap = new Map(Object.entries(json));

myMap = new Map([...myMap.entries()].sort((a, b) => a[1].value.localeCompare(b[1].value)));

myMap.forEach((x) => {
    console.log(x.value)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

To Sort Object simply use

```
const sortedObject = mapObject.sort((a,b)=>return b.value - a.value)
```

Comment: `sort()` is not a function on the `Map` type.