# Sorting JavaScript Object by property value (Numeric Key)

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, properties

**Hold Down! before marking as duplicate or voting down**

let's say I have a java Script Object as below and I wanna to sort this object by values, yes I know array is invented for it and has builtin `sort` but for some reason I have to go with this object :(

```
var myObj = {"you": 100, "me": 75,"11111": 20, "foo": 116, "bar": 15};
```

till now I end up with

```
{11111: 20, bar: 15, me: 75, you: 100, foo: 116}
```

but you can see it's not what you want, as in that case, I tried many solution from this deprived solution given here the code is below

```
Object
 .keys(myObj)
 .sort((a, b) => myObj[a]-myObj[b])
 .reduce((_sortedObj, key) => ({
   ..._sortedObj, 
   [key]: myObj[key]
 }), {})
```

**Edit** I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value) already it's not my case as I have numeric values so not any single answer given there helpful for me

Comment: since you have numerical keys, this is not possible

Comment: @adiga yes it's looks impossible in my mind, that's why I am asking here :(

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I thought that the properties of an object were unordered. :-/ (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-preserved)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this answer could possibly help you:

[Sort a dictionary by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500316/sort-a-dictionary-by-value-in-javascript)

After running the code in that answer on your dictionary I got this:

[image]

Is this something you could work with?

Comment: I think now it's looks impossible then I might be go with this solution, at least in that case I can display the correct result right now

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible.

In ES2015+, [the traversal order](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html) of object properties are:

- First, the keys that are **integer indices**, in ascending numeric order.
- Then, all other string keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
- Lastly, all symbol keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.

Even if you add the `11111` key at the end, it will always be fetched first when you use `Object.keys()` or `for...in` loops

```js
const obj = {};
obj["first"] = 1
obj["second"] = 2
obj["200"] = 200 // integer keys
obj["100"] = 100 

// 100 and 200 property will be moved to the top even if they are added in the end
// 200 was added before 100, but it will be printed after 100 
// because integer indices are traversed in ascending numeric order
console.log(obj) 

// 100 will be the first key
console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```

You could use use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object instead. It has key-value pairs and it remembers the original insertion order of the keys.

Comment: so it's impossible? can't do with any ugliest solution as well

Comment: @AbdulHameed no, you cannot do it. Relying on property ordering (even though it's now well-defined behavior) is a really bad idea because it makes fairly broad assumptions about object "life history".  It's a recipe for lots of terrible bugs.