# Sort an object according to its key inside

Tags: javascript

Help me to write a function which will sort an object :

I have an object like which will sort according to its key inside 'order':

```
var users = {
  certificate:'certificate of student',
  lessons:  {
        lession_1: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 1 },
        lession_2: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 2 },
        lession_4: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 4 },
        lession_3: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 3 }
    }
};
```

it should be after sorting:

```
var users = {
  certificate:'certificate of student',
  lessons:  {
        lession_1: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 1 },
        lession_2: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 2 },
        lession_3: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 3 },
        lession_4: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 4 }
    }
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried lodash utility _.sortBy({...users}, ['order']) , but index got modified.

Comment: `lessons` should be an array not an object, you can't sort keys in an object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a dictionary by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500316/sort-a-dictionary-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need turn lessons object to array, because [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) work only with **Array**.

   `const arrayLessons = Object.values(users.lessons);`
2. Now sorting the `arrayLessons` using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

   `const sortedArray = arrayLessons.sort((prev, next) => prev.order - next.order);`
3. Update data for object of **users**

   `users.lessons = sortedArray;`

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't sort keys of an object, you'll have to:

1. **Transform** the **object** into an **array**.
2. **Sort** the **array**.
3. **Transform** the **array** back into an **object**.

Here is an efficient way of doing that:

```js
var users = {
  certificate:'certificate of student',
  lessons:  {
        lession_1: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 1 },
        lession_2: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 2 },
        lession_4: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 4 },
        lession_3: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 3 }
   }
}; 

function sortLessons (obj) {
    obj.lessons = Object.entries(obj.lessons)
        .sort((prev, next) => prev[1].order - next[1].order)
        .reduce((acc, value) => {
            acc[value[0]] = value[1];
            return acc;
        }, {});
}

sortLessons(users);

console.log(users);
```

The [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) returns an array `[key, value]` for each entries.

Then the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function takes a `compareFunction`, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) says:

> If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).

By doing the difference `a - b`, in your case `4-3 = 1`, the `lesson_3` will be inserted before `lesson_4` and your array will be sorted.

Then the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function rebuilds the object.

Comment: @Alexander Good catch, It has been fixed !

Comment: Why do you think your solution is the most effective? In fact, you are doing 3 loop, when can two.

Comment: It is more effective in term of readability, development time and coding style and sometimes performance since standard library can be more optimized than custom algorithm using loops. Also you can't use 2 loops (if you refer to your answer it is incomplete with a wrong result) to answer the author question.

Comment: i mean re-usability, like i can pass parameter to a function like wise : (obj, lessons, order).

Comment: Ok, so the `lessons` is already in the `users` object so you dont' need to pass it has parameter and for the `order` you probably mean the sort function you can just put it as parameter of the function. Is it good like that or you want me to edit the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Key order for non-symbol properties [are now determined by insertion order](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) (as of ES6). With this in mind, you can extract the values of your `lesson` object, and then sort each object in your array of objects with `.sort()`. You can then loop over your sorted array and insert your objects into a new `.lessons` object in the order they appear in the sorted `order` array like so:

```js
const users = {
  certificate: 'certificate of student',
  lessons: {
    lession_1: {
      'user': 'fred',
      'order': 1
    },
    lession_2: {
      'user': 'barney',
      'order': 2
    },
    lession_4: {
      'user': 'fred',
      'order': 4
    },
    lession_3: {
      'user': 'barney',
      'order': 3
    }
  }
};

const sortObj = (obj) => {
  const order = Object.entries(obj.lessons).sort(([,a], [,b]) => a.order-b.order);
  obj.lessons = {};
  for(const [lesson, user] of order)
    obj.lessons[lesson] = user;

}

sortObj(users)
console.log(users);
```

However, I would suggest that you lean towards using arrays instead of objects if you're going to be working with ordering objects as it is much more intuitive:

```js
const users = {
  certificate: 'certificate of student',
  lessons: [
    {
      'user': 'fred',
      'order': 1
    },
    {
      'user': 'barney',
      'order': 2
    },
    {
      'user': 'fred',
      'order': 4
    },
    {
      'user': 'barney',
      'order': 3
    }
  ]
};

const sortObj = (obj) => {
  obj.lessons.sort((a, b) => a.order-b.order);
}

sortObj(users)
console.log(users);
```

Comment: Is something wrong with my answer? Please let me know if I've got something incorrect (not too sure what I've missed)

Comment: The `obj.lessons["lesson_"+(i+1)]` with hard coded value. You have to update your algorithm every time you'll update you're data. Also the loop for rebuilding the object is not really efficient when there is available builtin functions for that (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59768967/9434800))

Comment: Yes, it is hardcoded, that could be improved. But I wouldn't say that it makes this answer incorrect. I've updated it now to get the object's entries rather than hardcoding it. As for using a loop to rebuild the object, using `.reduce()` is also rebuilding the object under the hood, both perform the re-build logic. So using reduce isn't much more efficient than using a standard loop

Comment: I think it's better to use what your language has to offer rather than reinventing the wheel. Otherwise you could say the same thing for the `entries` or `sort` functions, actually for all the standard library since you could write all your code  using `for` loops and `if` statements. It is more efficient in term of development time to use what already exists and also in term of clarity when you want to read your code later (a function is for a specific task when a loop could do anything) and sometimes performance since standard library could be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:-

```
var users = {
  certificate:'certificate of student',
  lessons:  {
        lession_1: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 1 },
        lession_2: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 2 },
        lession_4: { 'user': 'fred',   'order': 4 },
        lession_3: { 'user': 'barney', 'order': 3 }
    }
}; 

keysSorted = Object.keys(users.lessons).sort(function(a,b){return users.lessons[a]['order']-users.lessons[b]['order']})   //get sorted keys

let sortedLessons={};

for(let key of keysSorted){
   sortedLessons[key]=users.lessons[key];
}

users.lessons=sortedLessons;
console.log(users)
```

Comment: There is bad code formatting (specially the function in `sort`). The for loop not efficient when you can use builtin array functions (cf `reduce`).  There is no explanations. In the end it's no easily readable and not efficient.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers