# Sort an array of objects with random values

Tags: javascript

total newbie here. I need to sort array of random objects (to pass data to machine I build). How to do that?

```
var array = [{fgy : 34}, {sor : 56}, {dtr : 45}];
```

`array.sort(function(a, b){return a- b;});` // ofcourse it is not working

Expected result:

```
fgy : 34, dtr : 45, sor : 56
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to sort on the value? Also, are you guaranteed that there will only be one key in each object? We need more info

Comment: This solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500316/sort-a-dictionary-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value) or what @MarioAbbruscato marked would serve your purpose better.

Comment: I want the object key (name) and a value - it could be string (all key/values combined in string). I think yes, every object is just one key/value pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that there will only be one key in each object, and all you are wanting to sort by is the value, here's how you can do that:

```js
var array = [{fgy : 34}, {sor : 56}, {dtr : 45}];

let sorted = array.slice().sort((a,b) => {
  let aVal = Object.values(a)[0];
  let bVal = Object.values(b)[0];
  return aVal - bVal;
});

console.log(sorted)
```

If multiple keys can be on each object, you just need to decide what you are sorting on and use that for your `aVal` and `bVal` in the `.sort()` function. For example, if you wanted to sort by the maximum value, you could do something like `let aVal = Math.max(...Object.values(a));`, similarly, you could do the sum of the values, minimum value, etc. You just need to assign *a* value to your `aVal` and `bVal` and then return the comparison.

#### ES5 syntax version (as requested in comments)

```js
var array = [{fgy : 34}, {sor : 56}, {dtr : 45}];

let sorted = array.slice().sort((a,b) => {
  var aVal = a[Object.keys(a)[0]];
  var bVal = b[Object.keys(b)[0]];
  return aVal - bVal;
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working on modern computer - however on an old machine it seems I can't use "let aVal = Object.values(a)[0];". Is there an 'older' (without synthetic sugar) code I can use? It could be long, it could be ugly I just need to pass the results in proper order so I can actually do my thing, and not programing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.sort method, But you need to get the value inside each Object in the array.
You can do it using `Object.values(obj)[0]`.
Which will return the first value in the object

For example:

```
let obj = { fgy: 34 }
console.log(Object.values(obj)[0]) // returns 34
```

Then you can use it with the sort method:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  return Object.values(a)[0] - Object.values(b)[0]
})
```

Comment: it is an array of objects, not a simple object.

Comment: @john The first code snippet is demonstrating how to grab the value of an unknown key out of an object with a single key, and the second snippet uses that to grab the value from each object to use for sorting